# Bitbucket activity graph

Tags: git, github, visualization, bitbucket

I would like to know if there is a solution in [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) similar to [Github](https://github.com/)'s graphs. For example, here are the ones for Node.js:

#### Contributions graph

[image: Node.js contributions graph]

#### Commits graph

[image: Node.js commits graph]

I've done some research and I haven't found anything similar. Does anybody know if this kind of visualisation exists in a hidden place in [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/)? Or is there some 3rd party service which provides these kinds of graphs of a git repository?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Take a look at [Awesome Graphs for Bitbucket add-on](http://stiltsoft.com/blog/2015/06/introducing-awesome-graphs-for-bitbucket-visualized-statistics-of-git-and-mercurial-repositories)

From http://blog.bitbucket.org/2015/06/10/atlassian-connect-for-bitbucket-a-new-way-to-extend-your-workflow-in-the-cloud

> If you are currently a user of Bitbucket and want to take a sneak peak, click on your avatar, select “Manage Account”, and simply install these new add-ons by selecting “Find new add-ons” from the left menu.

Here is the add-on's release notes page: https://docs.stiltsoft.com/awesome-graphs/cloud/release-notes-cloud

Comment: The add-on still is in the beta phase and we continue to improve it reliability. The major update have been completed about 17 hours ago so you can try it again. Please, let us know if the the problem persists. To submit a ticket, follow this link https://helpdesk.stiltsoft.com/support/feedback.html

Comment: Good, now it works. I accept your answer because it's the closest solution I've seen of the Github's graph, still it has a long way to go. I hope you'll add more stats in the future ;-)  Good luck.

Comment: Am I correct, that this add-on works only for a single repository, not for the all of commits?

Comment: You can see the graphs of any of repositories (with all it commits) you have access to. If you want see your personal contribution activity (all of your commits across multiple repos) -- it's about Contributions graph. Currently Contributions graph provided for Bitbucket Server (Stash) only:  https://goo.gl/30QlLQ However this graph is in our backlog. Also there is a feature request you can vote for: https://goo.gl/zop8oV

Comment: How to share it publicly though, like github, looks nice and everything, but only me can see it

Comment: To share graphs publicly, please install the app with the account context. First of all, refer to the article [Understanding app context](https://docs.stiltsoft.com/display/public/AwesomeGraphsBitbucket/Installation#Installation-Understandingappcontext) Then follow the instructions from the article [Installing with the account context](https://docs.stiltsoft.com/display/public/AwesomeGraphsBitbucket/Installation#Installation-Installingwiththeaccountcontext)

Comment: Any chance that you could adjust the pricing so it is not exponential (25 users $150/y, 250 users $1600/y)? 

A general gripe about the Atlassian Marketplace price structure; In our case, we have added 200 users on our license so that we can provide read access to our repositories, but that does not mean that many of these will be using all the bells and whistles. It certainly does not mean that we have budget for paying for all features for all users. I.e. as we have grown, we can no longer use features that are only used by a handful of people, without setting up separate installations.

Comment: Hi there! The app version for Bitbucket Cloud is free. In your case, as you use Bitbucket Server, these restrictions are caused by [Atlassian licensing policy](https://www.atlassian.com/licensing/purchase-licensing), so we can’t implement changes in it on the Marketplace.
Please, write to us to discuss this question [here](https://stiltsoft.customercase.com/forums/support-requests/ideas/create?category=Awesome%20Graphs%20for%20Bitbucket). We will try to figure out how to help you with your case.

Answer (score 11):

Click on account at top-right corner -> integrations -> Awesome Graphs -> add

Answer (score 3):

I used gitstats and it was amazing.  Just what I was looking for.

http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/

I just cloned the repo, installed gnuplot with homebrew on OSX, and voila.  I had full nice stats in a few seconds.  No need to have admin permissions to install in bitbucket.  No use of the cloud and giving others view of my stats.  It produces a TON of nice charts.  Not probably as pretty as true professional ones, but did the job for sure.

Here's a quick example of a rewrite of our apps to Flutter:

[image]

Comment: thanks, yea, this is a really old package but still worked for my purpose

Comment: doesn't seem to exist anymore for mac os (head-only brew packages were removed)